# Printing random lines from a file in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, random, file

Is [this](https://github.com/Shifterovich/CorrectHorse) the most efficient solution or can the performance be improved? Just opens a file and prints random words (lines with newlines stripped out).

```
import random

filename = "20k.txt"

def main(filename):
    words_file = open(filename, 'r')

    words = words_file.read().split("\n")
    temp_words = []
    for word in words:
        temp_words.append(word.strip("\r"))
    words = temp_words

    while True:
        length = int(raw_input("Words:"))
        for i in range(0,length):
            print(words[random.randrange(0,len(words)+1)]),
        print("\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(filename)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should always `close` your files. Or, use the `with` keyword, which takes care of this for you.

Then, the `'r'` mode is already the default mode for opening a file. Also, consider storing your words in a `set`, instead of a list (gets rid of duplicate words, which might be wanted, or not if you want a higher probability for some words).

You should consider using `random.choice` to get a random element from an iterable (actually an iterable with `len` defined).

I would also separate the file reading into a separate method. and make it more explicit what the prompt actually means (the number of words to generate).

I would use `str.join` and give it a generator expression rather than multiple calls to `print`.

```
import random

def get_words(file_name):
    with open(filename) as word_file:
        return list(set(word.strip() for word in word_file))


def random_words(n, words)
    return " ".join(random.choice(words) for _ in range(n))


def main(file_name):
    words = get_words(file_name)
    while True:
        n = int(raw_input("Number of words:"))
        print(random_words(n, words))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_name = "20k.txt"
    main(file_name)
```

Comment: Right, I forgot about the `close`. Using a `set` is a better option, yes. Didn't know about `random.choice`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your code ran: `TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing`

Comment: What does `.strip()` do without any arguments?

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich It strips away whitespace from the edges, including all kinds of line-breaks. So `"  asgsg  \n\r\n".strip() == 'asgsg'`.

Comment: Your answer contains `words_file = open(filename)` and `with open(filename) as word_file:`. I guess the first line is a mistake?

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich Yes, it was me doing too much copy & pasting...edited

Comment: Yeah. I made your code slightly shorter (put it all into `main`). Works very smoothly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You would greatly improve performance if you stop reading the whole 20k lines file into memory. The difference for 100 executions (3 words per execution) is 0.018 vs 0.793 seconds.

I suggest you to use word_file.seek method instead. It manipulates stream position to read just the word you need, not the whole file.

To get random position, use random.randint(0, EOF).

Details are here: https://github.com/artgromov/CorrectHorse.

I have made pull request to your repo.

Comment: I should've specified it's Python 2.7